# Get k8s namespace inside spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud

I have a spring boot application ( set of services ) deployed in k8s cluster. For micromter metrics I need to dynamically get the namespace this application runs so that i can add that as tag in metrics. Following is my custom tag creation bean

```
@Bean
public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
return registry -> {
  String hostname = getHostName();
  registry.config().commonTags(TAG_NAME_INSTANCE,hostname);

  final String applicationName = environment.getProperty(SPRING_BOOT_APPLICATION_NAME_PROPERTY_KEY);
  registry.config().commonTags(TAG_NAME_APPLICATION, applicationName);
  registry.config().commonTags(TAG_NAME_APP, applicationName);

  registry.config().commonTags(TAG_NAME_KUBE_NAME_SPACE, getKubeNamespace());
};
```

}

currently `getKubeNamespace` return hard coded value. How can i get which namespace this pod is running ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kubernetes has a feature for accessing such fields, it's called the [Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/) .

With the help of the Downward API the pod's namespace can be accessed by defining an environment variable in the pod's definition like this:

```
- name: NAMESPACE
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

After that, the environment variable can be read by Spring:

```
@Value("${NAMESPACE}")
private String namespace;
```

Comment: I think this is the best and cleanest approach. Just provide it as env variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *Spring Cloud* there is no need to add an environment variable. Just use this property:

```
@Value("${spring.cloud.kubernetes.client.namespace}")
private String namespace;
```